# Can Jekyll serve files when a directory of the same name exists?

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple use case on a site that I am publishing with Jekyll:

- I need to list values of a certain type. Let's say one type has URIs of the form `.../base/typex/value`. I am generating a file `.../typex/value.md` and Jekyll happily serves it.
- I also want to serve pages listing all values. That page should be named `.../base/typex` or `.../base/typex/` (I don't mind either way).
- I cannot use the file `.../base/typex/index.md` to do this because in some cases, `index` is actually a valid value.
- I am creating `.../base/typex.md`, but Jekyll ignores it, regardless of the permalink that I put in there that specifically has no trailing slash. Instead of serving the file, Jekyll serves the directory listing.

Is there any way I can solve this puzzle? If Jekyll had support for serving `.../base/typex.md`, everything would be good, but it seems as if as soon as there is a directory `.../base/typex/`, Jekyll simply ignores this file. Is there any workaround or configuration I can use? (And this is going to get hosted on GitHub, so I have no control over the Web server configuration.)

( *https://github.com/dret/webconcepts/issues/25 has the backstory, in case anybody is interested. But the issue is fully described here, so there is no need to follow that link.* )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce it with your provided repository, thanks for that!

If you create a file `http-method.md` in `/concepts` and set the permalink to 
`permalink: /concepts/http-method/`, my local jekyll serves the page both in `/concepts/http-method` and `/concepts/http-method/`

Comment: thanks for the response! https://github.com/dret/webconcepts is the repo. specifically, i would like to serve lists of values at `http://webconcepts.info/concepts/http-method` (404 right now) and concrete values at `http://webconcepts.info/concepts/http-method/GET`. my current ugly workaround is that the list is actually served at `http://webconcepts.info/concepts/http-methods` (notice the trailing 's'). this works, but now the URIs aren't easily hackable, and it would be nice if they were.

Comment: as an added complication, i really want to avoid serving URIs with extensions because these URIs are supposed to be used as identifiers, and thus having specifics in them such as file extensions is not something i want to do.

Comment: thanks! i think i missed how crucial the trailing `/` on the permalink is. without it, nothing works. http://webconcepts.info/update/2016/12/15/hackable-concept-URIs.html documents the changes i made thanks to your help! thank you very much!